# How would I implement the Outlet tag in React alongside my root path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, vite

For example, I have this code where I want the root path to be the `DemoApp` component:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import SignInForm from "./components/SignIn/SignInForm";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import SignUpForm from "./components/SignUp/SignUpForm";
import DemoSignIn from "./components/DemoSignIn/DemoSignIn";
import DemoApp from "./components/DemoSignIn/DemoApp/DemoApp";
import DemoDashboard from "./components/DemoSignIn/DemoDashboard/DemoDashboard";
import "./App.css";

export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignInForm />} />
        <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUpForm />} />
        <Route path="/demo-sign-in" element={<DemoSignIn />} />
        <Route path="/demo-dashboard" element={<DemoDashboard />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<DemoApp />}>
          <Route path="demo-dashboard" index element={<DemoDashboard />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but I also want to have the `DemoDashboard` component rendered via the `Outlet` tag in the root path inside my `DemoApp` component. This is my `DemoApp` component

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./DemoApp.module.css";
import HeadNavBar from "../DemoDashboard/HeadNavBar";
import SideNavBar from "../DemoDashboard/SideNavBar";
import DemoDashboard from "../DemoDashboard/DemoDashboard";

const DemoApp = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles["demo-app"]}>
      <div className={styles["head-nav"]}>
        <HeadNavBar />
      </div>
      <div className={styles["side-nav"]}>
        <SideNavBar />
      </div>
      <main className={styles["main-content"]}>
        <Outlet />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DemoApp;
```

Right now when I start up the server it renders the `DemoApp` component on the root path but not the `DemoDashboard` component inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really specify a `path` prop ***and*** the `index` prop at the same time on the same `Route` component, it's rather one or the other. If you want the `DemoDashboard` component to also render when the path is `"/"` then you'll need an additional index route that renders it.

Example:

```
export default function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignInForm />} />
        <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        <Route path="/sign-up" element={<SignUpForm />} />
        <Route path="/demo-sign-in" element={<DemoSignIn />} />
        <Route path="/demo-dashboard" element={<DemoDashboard />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<DemoApp />}>
          <Route
            index                 // <-- rendered on "/"
            element={<DemoDashboard />}
          />
          <Route
            path="demo-dashboard" // <-- rendered on "/demo-dashboard"
            element={<DemoDashboard />}
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I noticed it still works if I delete the demo-dashboard path. If I want to make the root path render the DemoDashboard component, then do I even need a separate demo-dashboard path?

Comment: @gtrman97 Nope, the `"/demo-dashboard"` route isn't needed if you only want to render the dashboard when exactly on the parent `"/"` route path.